# hibernate update object partially

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I have this  model and hibernate mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "candidate")
public class Candidate extends Person {

   private Set<Vacancy> vacancies= new HashSet<Vacancy>();

   @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinTable(name = "candidate_vacancy", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "candidate_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "vacancy_id"))
        public Set<Vacancy> getVacancies() {
        return vacancies;
    }

    public void setVacancies(Set<Vacancy> vacancies) {
        this.vacancies = vacancies;
    }
}
```

Person class:

```
            @MappedSuperclass
            public abstract class Person {
            private Integer id;
            private String name;
            @Id
                @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
                @Column (name = "id")
                public Integer getId() {
                    return id;
                }

                public void setId(Integer id) {
                    this.id = id;
                }
             @Column(name = "name")
             @NotEmpty
             public String getName() {
              return name;
             }

             public void setName(String name) {
              this.name = name;
            }


 }
```

vacancy mapping

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "vacancy")
@XmlRootElement(name="vacancy")

    public class Vacancy {
    ...
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "vacancies", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public Set<Candidate> getCandidates() {
            return candidates;
    ...
       }
}
```

And I have so html form:

```
<form action="saveCandidate" method="POST">
        name: <input type="text" value="${candidate.name}" name="name" />
        <input  type="hidden" name="id" value="${candidate.id}"> 
                <input  type="submit" value="save changes" />
</form>
```

I handle my form in my @controller method:

```
 public String saveCandidate(Model model, @ModelAttribute Candidate candidate) {
    candidateService.update(candidate);
            return "candidateMenu";
   }
```

Using this way, I have problem. vacancies related for candodate  delete from my database. I fix it so:

```
public String saveCandidate(Model model, @ModelAttribute Candidate candidate) {
            Candidate candidate2 =  candidateService.findById(candidate.getId());
        candidate.setName(candidate2.getName());
        candidate.setSurname(candidate2.getSurname());
        candidate.setPhone(candidate2.getPhone());
        candidate.setResumeUrl(candidate2.getResumeUrl());
        candidateService.update(candidate2);
        return "candidateMenu";
    }
```

But I think it is very bad way for solving my problem.

P.S. I know that fetchType.lazy is bad, but I don't want  replace it.

Comment: "I know that fetchType.lazy is bug" <-- how do you know that? do you understand the difference between `EAGER`and `LAZY` fetch types?

Comment: not bug, bad style  I think

Comment: I understand differencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load your entity first from DB and then let spring bind request parameters to your entity properties.

So something like below might work

```
    @ModelAttribute
    public Candidate loadCandidate(@RequestParam(value="id",required=false) Long id) {
      Candidate candidate=null;
      if(id!=null){
        candidate=candidateService.findById(id);
      }
      else{
       candidate=new Candidate();
      }

      return candidate;
     }

    @RequestMapping(.......)
    public String saveCandidate(Model model, @ModelAttribute Candidate candidate) {
        candidateService.update(candidate);
          return "candidateMenu";
     }
```

As `loadCandidate()` method is annotated with `@ModelAttribute` annotation ,so `loadCandidate()` will be invoked before any of requestmapping handlers in your controller.
so In your case `loadCandidate()` will be invoked before `saveCandidate()`

Comment: Where I must invoke loadCandidate() method ?

Comment: You dont need to invoke loadCandidate() method ..spring will automatically invokes this method as it is anotated with @ModelAttribute

Comment: moment, I will try it

Comment: @user2674303 if answer is helpful then please accept the answer

Comment: if I invoke this object in view this object will be load otherwise no?

Comment: @user2674303 you can use this modelattribute just like any other requestattribute in you view.